# Is it allowed to change the values given to the mongo reduce function?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

For instance, is the following reduce function valid?

```
function reduce(key, values) {
  values[0].push(100); // each value of the values list is a list itself. 
  return values[0];
}
```

I know this function is not terribly useful, but is it valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to, just remember MongoDB reduce functions must be idempotent: the same structure of the input keys must be the output structure so the reduce can be called multiple times.

As long as you provide a valid output record, you can manipulate its contents as much as you like.  But the general rule to achieve idempotence is that whatever the structure / content of your MAP value is, should be the structure / content of your reduce output.